# Find the boundary, the interior and exterior of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to find the boundary, the interior and exterior of the following set:
$$S=\{(x,y)\in R^2 : x>0,y=\sin(1/x)\}$$

I think that the interior should be the empty set because every open ball with center in $z\in S$ also intersects its complement, right?
Also, I think that the exterior is $R^2-S$ and the boundary is S.

But what I'm not sure about is if set of points  $(0,y) , y\in[-1,1]$ are also part of the boundary. It seems to me that every open ball with center in $(0,y)$ intersects with the curve $\sin(1/x)$, how can I prove (or disprove) it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y\in [-1,1]$ consider the set

$T:=\{t>0 : \sin(t)=y\}$.

It is non-empty, and for every $t_0\in T$ the numbers $t+2\pi$ are in $T$ too. Hence in every interval $[0,\epsilon]$ there are infinitely many solutions of the equation $y=\sin(1/x)$, which shows that $(0,y)$ is a boundary point of $S$.